# Delphi: Calling an executable from soap dll (IIS)

Tags: delphi, iis, soap, shellexecute

A SOAP DLL got an API to execute an exe file that is located on a different folder. I use ShellExecute to do so including the path+name and params.

ShellExecute returns 42 (>32, which is an OK code) but the executable is not running (it's a command line executable). Running it manually from a CMD does work. I tried with and without " around the path+name but nothing seems to work.

Because of the OK code, I have no idea where to begin searching for the cause.

Any idea what can I do? Maybe it's an access right issue because it's a soap that is trying to run an EXE file? If so, how can I check if this is the problem?

Comment: ShellExecute is the wrong function. Call CreateProcess to start an executable.

Comment: Will give it a try. from curiosity, what is the problem of ShellExecute in this context?

Comment: It should work fine but why talk to the shell when you want to create a process. I don't think changing will solve your problem. Anyway, if ShellExecute succeeds then the executable is running. Nobody here can reproduce your problem. Try some debugging. Trace debugging probably.

Comment: I use debugging and everything seems to be OK but the exe is not running. I thought maybe it's because I'm trying to run an exe from soap/IIS and a security definition that I don't know about.

Comment: If 42 is returned then it is running